# Seeking clarity regards C++ static member initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, static-members

I am quite confused regarding intialization and usage of C++ class/struct **static** members.

Let's say, that I have defined a struct `MapMetaData` in a header file named `Constants.h`. Here's how it looks -

```
struct MapMetaData {
            
            
            static float cell_size_, origin_x_, origin_y_;
            static unsigned int height_, width_;
            
            

        };
```

Now, let's say I am using this `struct` in some source file.

I don't understand why can't I just directly do

`MapMetaData::cell_size_ = my_value`

instead of

`float MapMetaData::cell_size = 0.0; // intializing the static member MapMetaData::cell_size_ = my_value`?  // then assigning some value to it

- Why do I need to explicily initialize the static member?
- While initializing, why do I need to specify the 'float' specifier?
- Why do I need to do the initialization globally? Why can't I just initalize it inside the scope of some function and then use it inside some another function because it is a static member after all?

Trying to call `MapMetaData::cell_size_ = my_value` directly without initializing, I get

```
undefined reference to MapMetaData::origin_x_
```

error.

Comment: What you're doing in the structure is to *declare* the variables. Then you need to *define* them. But there's no need to do explicit initialization of the variables when you define them. A definition like `float MapMetaData::cell_size_;` is perfectly fine, and will set the value to `0.0f`. If you want to skip separate declaration and definition, you could mark the members as `inline`. As in `inline static float cell_size_;`

Comment: On a different note, you almost *never* need to use `float` variables or values. Use `double` instead.

Comment: You are confusing *declaration*, *definition*, *initialization* and *assignment*. Until you understand the differences nothing is going to make sense. So understand the **concepts** first, then worry about the syntax,

Comment: For example, a failure to initialize is never going to cause an undefined reference error, but a failure to define might. You can define and initialize in the same line of code (though you don't have to) but they are different things.

Comment: Also, what requirement lead to the design and implementation where you have `static` member variables here? What is the purpose of these variables? What original problem are they supposed to solve?

Answer (score 2):

The **declaration** in `Constants.h` tells the compiler that there will be a static variable `MapMetaData::cell_size`. This gives the variable a name and modules including `Constants.h` can then refer to that variable.

Later, that would usually be in `Constants.cpp`, the variable is **defined**:

```
float MapMetaData::cell_size = 0.0f;  // Explicit initialization
```

which tells the compiler to allocate a piece of memory in the program to store the variable. The **initialization** (`... = 0.0f;`) tells the compiler which value to place in that piece of memory when the program starts. Static variables are always initialized. If no value is provided, i.e.:

```
float MapMetaData::cell_size;  // Implicit initialization
```

then the variable is initialized to "0" (this is not necessarily the case for non-static variables).

If the variable definition is omitted, then the storage for the variable will not be created and thus the linker cannot create the program because it cannot resolve the references to the variable. Thus an error message is given like the one you observed.

Later, you may **assign** a value to the variable:

```
MapMetaData::cell_size = my_value;
```

this tells the compiler to create code which copies the contents of `my_value` to `MapMetaData::cell_size`.

Thus, these lines of code are not redundant. Each have a specific function.

Comment: "these statements" - only the assignment is a _statement_. Declarations (including definitions) are not statements. This is why declarations can occur outside functions.

Comment: @MSalters You are right, of course. Changed to "these lines of code". Thanks.